# python: how do I give the option to the user to restart the program from the top if he chooses to do so?

Tags: javascript, python, pycharm

I made a mini mortgage calculator as practice (I am a beginner) and at the end of the code, I would like to ask the user if they want to recalculate from the beginning, making the program jump back to the first line of code, or give them the option to exit.

I have tried to add the line:
def main():

and then indent the rest of the program, so at the end I can use if and else method to either recall the program by simply saying

if ask == yes:
   main ()

however this does not seem to work. Whenever I add "main ()" at the top of my code, and click "run", the program doesnt run altogether. Just nothing happens. I have tried doing while loops but then im not sure what to put at the end.

```
def main():
  numbers = [61]
  for x_count in numbers:
  output = ""
  for count in range(x_count):
    output += "x"
  print(output)
  print("                          Mortgage Calculator                 ")
  print("*************************************************************")
  print("                                                             ")
  name = input("Enter your full name: ")
  price = int(input("Enter the price of the property: "))
  ask = input("Do you know your interest rate? Enter Y for yes, N for no: ")
  incentive = input("Have you owned a property in the past 5 years?")
```

that is only the beginning of the code. the end is:

end_code = input("Would you like to recalculate? press Y for yes, N for no: ")
if ask.upper == "Y" 
     main ()
else
   breakpoint()

As evident, I was expecting the program to call the main() and then restart, but that does not work. However, the program does not even start when I use that method of restarting program.

Comment: You could easily wrap your `main()` logic in a `while True:` and then the method reloops at the end...try this, if you need an example I can provide but this is very simple.

Answer (score 1):

Most apps have a "Main" loop.  If your program started with a simple:

```
def main():

    keepRunning=True

    while keepRunning:
        keepRunning = runMortgageCalculator()
```

At that point all the code you have now would go into runMortgageCalculator() and it would return a "true" to keep going and a "False" to end.

There, I think I got the python syntax right now, if not please enhance or comment.

Comment: keepRunning=True

    while keepRunning:
        keepRunning = mortgagecalculator()                                                                                             now what do i add at the end so that i can give the option to the user to either recalculate or end the program?